# Get selection start container when selecting a line and the blank space before it in contentEditable

Tags: javascript, range, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable element.
I do not allow any element in the content editable besid an `<a>` tag and a `<br>` tag.

I would like to know when a user selects a range and get the start container & end container.

Consider the following content in the editable element:

`<div id="div1" contenteditable="true">bla bla &nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>bla2 bla2<br>awsome<br>foobar&nbsp;</div>`

Heres a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r80dfr72/7/) to help demonstrate this.

When a user selects content the starts after the last character of some line (or better yet, at the beginning of a new empty line) and ends wherever - the range object returned by `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)` states that the start container is the editable element itself , and not the last child node selected.

How can I know the correct start container?

Steps for reproducing:

1. Open the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r80dfr72/7/) and open web console.
2. Start selecting text using your mouse from the end of the text (including the last space [`&nbps;` char]) and release your mouse **just before** the last space in the first line.
3. Look at the web console logs: it says the start container is the editable div instead of the text node last chosen (that contains only one char - an `&nbsp;`)
4. This also happens when you release your mouse just before the end of the empty line, not selecting its content.

Comment: You still have a precise location for the selection boundary, so what's the problem?

Comment: I expect the start container to be the first child node in the selection, but instead I'm getting the editable itself it that property, meaning I can't know which child nodes are in the selection.
Another example of this situation is, If a user starts a new line, Chrome adds a new empty text node, and when the caret is inside it the range returned also says the `commonAncestorContainer` is the element itself, again meaning I can't know where in the editable the caret is and act accordingly.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand what you meant by 'You still have a precise location for the selection boundary'. Which boundaries do I have?

Comment: It sounds like you're expecting the selection boundaries (i.e. the start and end) to lie within a text node, which isn't always the case. If, say, the `startContainer` property of the selection range is your editable element and the `startOffset` property is 1, that means the range starts directly after the first child node of the editable element.